# PHP: Large order form. How to correctly setup with arrays in html and to retrive it in post

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a very large orderform, where customers can order different food.

Here is an example of my html (not completely sure if this is the correct way):

```
<legend>Dinner</legend>
<label for="beef">Beef</label>
<input type="text" id="beef" name="order[]dinner[][beef]" placeholder="How many beef plates do you want?">

<label for="chicken">Chicken</label>
<input type="text" id="chicken" name="order[]dinner[][chicken]" placeholder="How many chicken plates do you want?">


<legend>Desserts</legend>
<label for="cake">Cake</label>
<input type="text" id="cake" name="order[]desserts[][cake]" placeholder="How many cake slices do you want?">

<label for="pudding">Pudding</label>
<input type="text" id="pudding" name="order[]pudding[][cake]" placeholder="How many puddings do you want?">
```

How could I make a forloop to collect all the orders (where the value is over 0)

I have tried this code:

```
$order_array = $_POST['order'];

foreach ($order_array AS $key => $value){
    $order .= "<p><strong>$key:</strong> $value</p>\n";
}
```

But the output is this:

0: 30
1: 2

I would like it to be:

Beef: 30
Chicken: 1

Also, if possible could display the "category" like:

**Dinner:**
Beef: 30
Chicken: 1

**Dessert:**
Cake: 29
Pudding: 2

## Edit:

Here is my post array:

```
array (
  'order' => 
    'Dinner' => 
    array (
      'beef' => '',
      'chicken' => '40',
    ),
    'Dessert' => 
    array (
      'Cake' => '',
      'Pudding' => '',
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your inputs so that their names are in the following format:

`<input name="order[category][food]" />`

Then, once the data has been posted you can do something like the following to get the desired output:

```
if (!empty($_POST['order'])) {

  foreach ($_POST['order'] as $type => $items) {
    echo '<strong>' . ucfirst($type) . '</strong><br />';

    foreach ($items as $name => $qty) {
      echo ucfirst($type) . ': ' . $qty . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';
  }
}
```

Which would output something like the following:-

**Dinner**
Beef: 12
Chicken: 2
**Dessert**
Cake: 4
Pudding: 1

---

**Edit:** If you need to prevent displaying categories (`$type`) from showing if there are no `$items` in them, you can do the following:

```
if (count(array_filter($items))) {
  echo '<strong>' . ucfirst($type) . '</strong><br />';
}
```

Comment: This looks correct, but my output is this:

0:

0:Array

1:

1:Array

2:

2:Array

3:

3:Array

4:

4:Array

5:

5:Array

Comment: Yes, I hade order[][dinner][chicken]. Changed that and everything works, except the: if (!empty($_POST['order'])) { does not seem to work, because I get the empty $names also in my output.

Comment: I added this if check: if ($qty > "0"){ echo $name: $qty} to prevent empty $qty to display. But how could I write a same type of check to prevent the "category" to be printed if there was no food in the category?

Comment: Hmm, does not seem like it. Still get all the categories with that extra check (even the empty ones).

Comment: Updated question with $_POST array

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<legend>Dinner</legend>
<label for="beef">Beef</label>
<input type="text" id="beef" name="order[beef]" placeholder="How many beef plates do you want?">

<label for="chicken">Chicken</label>
<input type="text" id="chicken" name="order[chicken]" placeholder="How many chicken plates do you want?">


<legend>Desserts</legend>
<label for="cake">Cake</label>
<input type="text" id="cake" name="order[cake]" placeholder="How many cake slices do you want?">

<label for="pudding">Pudding</label>
<input type="text" id="pudding" name="order[pudding]" placeholder="How many puddings do you want?">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
 $order_array = $_GET['order'];

print_r($order_array);
foreach ($order_array AS $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code it works for :

Beef: 30

Chicken: 1

```
<form>
<legend>Dinner</legend>
<label for="beef">Beef</label>
<input type="text" id="beef" name="order[beef]" placeholder="How many beef plates do you want?">

<label for="chicken">Chicken</label>
<input type="text" id="chicken" name="order[chicken]" placeholder="How many chicken plates do you want?">

<legend>Desserts</legend>
<label for="cake">Cake</label>
<input type="text" id="cake" name="order[cake]" placeholder="How many cake slices do you want?">

<label for="pudding">Pudding</label>
<input type="text" id="pudding" name="order[pudding]" placeholder="How many puddings do you want?">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $order_array = $_POST['order'];

    $order = "";
    foreach ($order_array AS $key => $value){
        $order .= "<p><strong>$key:</strong> $value</p>\n";
    }

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($order);
}
?>
```